# Mojang API get UUID of player at unix timestamp (api not working?)

Tags: node.js, uuid

Using the Mojang API to get the past UUID of a player with the given timestamp

Using a GET request with this endpoint:(https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/coined?at=1577664000)

The issue is, this is only getting the current UUID of the player currently holding the username, its ignoring the timestamp all together, and not getting the UUID from the past username, with the timestamp given.

Per the API documentation,

```
GET https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/<username>?at=<timestamp>
This will return the UUID of the name at the timestamp provided.

?at=0 can be used to get the UUID of the original user of that username, however, it only works if the name was changed at least once, or if the account is legacy.

The timestamp is a Unix timestamp (without milliseconds)
When the `at` parameter is not sent, the current time is used
```

Let me know if I am overlooking something incredibly simple here, or if its just the API. I've also tried using the API wrapper for node and its still giving the same issue.

EDIT: Appears the timestamp function of the api has been removed out of the blue, as per reports on the bug tracker. Seems like this functionality with the api will no longer be possible :/

Comment: If you want to get the past usernames of a profile, you could use   

`https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/<uuid>/names`
in your case:
`https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/02ec8a8ed7234fa993fdf8adb4cf333e/names`
or do you want the usernames at a specific time?

Comment: Not trying to get past usernames, that works fine. Trying to get the UUID of a username, at a given time. Since UUID changes between usernames, for example I want the UUID of the account that held the name "coined" say 2 years ago, not the current account uuid that holds it. The API seems to disregard the timestamp to get previous UUIDs associated to the username, and only gets the current